# Select information in sqlite database using a cursor - android studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor

I have a problem to display a data from my database using a cursor.

Here is my code for the SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
package com.example.kazo.pal;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//The Android's default system path of your application database.

private static String DB_NAME = "dbTest2";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;


/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {

            copyDataBase();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            throw new Error("Error copying database");

        }
    }

}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}


/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if(myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDataBase) {

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase myDataBase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}


public Cursor getC(String Prenom) {
    Cursor c=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable where prenom=?", new String [] {Prenom});
    c.moveToFirst();

    return c;
}


}
```

Here is my code for my main activity:

```
package com.example.kazo.pal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView monTexte = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

    try {

        myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String nom=myDbHelper.getC("alex").getString(2);


    monTexte = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.db);
    monTexte.setText(nom);


}}
```

When I run the application this way, it works and my data is diplayed in the activity, but when I modify the following line of code:

```
Cursor c=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable where prenom=?", new String [] {Prenom});
```

to:

```
Cursor c=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT nom FROM myTable where prenom=?", new String [] {Prenom});
```

the application crashes.

What is the problem ? Why does my application crash when I do this modification ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use SQL query it returns cursor positioned before the first entry. That is strange, but that's how it works.

So you have to move the cursor to some valid position before retrieving of the data. It can be c.moveToFirst(), c.moveTpLast() or others.

Comment: Ok thank you, but even when I let "c.moveToFirst()", the application crashes when I use the following line of code: "Cursor c=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT nom FROM myTable where prenom=?", new String [] {Prenom});"     Why?

Comment: So the problem is not in that line.
The error occurs when you reach:
 
`String nom=myDbHelper.getC("alex").getString(2);`
 
In the getString(int i) method of the cursor you have to indicate the index of the column you want to reach, but here you have the only column. If you want to reach the 3rd row of the results, you better type this:


`c=myDbHelper.getC("alex");
c.moveToPosition(2);
String nom=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex('nom'));`

Answer (score 0):

```java
String nom=myDbHelper.getC("alex").getString(2);
```

You are trying to read the third column of the result.
This does not work when you are selecting a single column.